# Checkout cart error: The requested qty is not available

Tags: magento2, cart, stock, out-of-stock, magento2.4.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.4, clients reported issues with the items in the cart, and I'm able to simulate by having two carts in different clients' accounts with the same item that has 1 item in stock.
The error message is below.

**The requested qty is not available**

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you have the **Inventory Check on cart load** disabled.

This is a new option that exists to improve the checkout performance, but you can easily disable it on:

**Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options**

Disabling the inventory check can improve performance for checkout steps, especially when there are many items in the cart. But if this inventory check is skipped, some out-of-stock scenarios could throw other types of errors, including:

- The requested qty is not available
- Unable to place an order: Enter a valid payment method and try again.
- Unable to place an order: There are no source items with the in-stock status.
- The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.